# injecting angular ui bootstrap into app.js, but the datepicker is not showing in view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I'm trying to configure a datepicker using the angular-ui-bootstrap plugin.

I've downloaded and installed everything ok, but now the datepicker isn't showing in my view. I'm not getting any errors - it just doesn't render out in the view. I'm new to angular so a little lost.

Here is my code:

app.js - I'm injecting the datepicker here.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'stripe', 'ui.router','ui.bootstrap',  'ui.bootstrap.datepicker', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

blah blah
```

Then the controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment',   function($scope, Appointment) {


//for the date picker directives

$scope.dateTimeNow = function() {
    $scope.date = new Date();
  };
  $scope.dateTimeNow();

  $scope.toggleMinDate = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };

  $scope.maxDate = new Date('2014-06-22');
  $scope.toggleMinDate();

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    startingDay: 1,
    showWeeks: false
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(calendarDate, mode) {
    return mode === 'day' && ( calendarDate.getDay() === 0 || calendarDate.getDay() === 6 );
  };

  $scope.hourStep = 1;
  $scope.minuteStep = 15;

  $scope.timeOptions = {
    hourStep: [1, 2, 3],
    minuteStep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
  };

  $scope.showMeridian = true;
  $scope.timeToggleMode = function() {
    $scope.showMeridian = !$scope.showMeridian;
  };

  $scope.resetHours = function() {
    $scope.date.setHours(1);
  };

}]);
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.2.1/angular-strap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.2.1/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>


<!-- for datetimepicker-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<!-- ENDS for datetimepicker-->


<!-- Stripe includes-->

 <script type="text/javascript" src="components/stripe-angular/stripe-angular.js"></script>

<!-- Ends Stripe includes -->
```

html for datepicker:

```
<datetimepicker min-date="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks" hour-step="hourStep" minute-step="minuteStep" ng-model="formData.date" show-meridian="showMeridian" date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy" date-options="dateOptions"  readonly-time="false"></datetimepicker>
```

I'm also including 
1) the stylesheet
2) the datepicker.js
3) all of bootstrap etc.

in the index.html

What could i have missed?

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle or something?

Comment: here's a plunkr but its not working either - http://plnkr.co/edit/nla2HP7Fpz3MAK3Ko7I2?p=preview - sorry I'm a total noob

Comment: Before solving your original problem, you've forgot to import several javascript files on your plunkr. angular-resource.js, datetimepicker.js... Please check the console log on plunkr.

Comment: sorry - made adjustments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add not only 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker' but also 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker' on your module dependencies.

Your app.js should be like this.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [...'ui.bootstrap.datepicker', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker'])
```

Comment: facepalm!! I'm such an idiot - that's 90 minutes of my life I wont get back

Comment: still - learnt something about the importance of dependency injection